# Google maps api key for mobile

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, key

We are building hybrid app which will be on ios and android.

Our app is using google static map api. I'm not sure if we need ios key or web key for that.

right now I just generated web key, but then how authentication of key will work on it, since its not ios SDK map.

Comment: Well, google static maps api accepts only web key. The iOS key is for Google Maps SDK for iOS.

Comment: ya, but then anyone can use my key for there project. no?

Comment: Pass your api key with `key` parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Static Maps API needs a web api key.
Pass your API KEY with 'key' parameter like below.

> https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=Brooklyn+Bridge,New+York,NY&zoom=13&size=600x300&maptype=roadmap
>   &markers=color:blue%7Clabel:S%7C40.702147,-74.015794&markers=color:green%7Clabel:G%7C40.711614,-74.012318
>   &markers=color:red%7Clabel:C%7C40.718217,-73.998284
>   &key=YOUR_API_KEY

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps/intro

Comment: how would it secure the key from other developers using it? cause then anyone can grab the key and start using it.

Comment: If your app hosts on "file://", static maps api should work without api key. key is for webdomain. If your app hosts on "http://localhost" is also, you don't need it. But these are currently. If you need to pass your key, you should pass your key with signature parameter. Read **Key and signature parametes** in this page https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps/intro

Answer (score 0):

Static Maps API has nothing to do with iOS and Android Maps SDKs. It is a separate API so you need the Static Maps API enabled on the project and generate a key for this API.

It simply allows you to embed a map image in your app, but the downside is that it cannot be made interactive.

A very useful tip on using the Static Maps API on a mobile device is to look at screen resolution of the target device and adjust the [scale parameters](http://here:https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps/intro#scale_values).